# Cocoapods for Swift, linker command failed for Release scheme

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm using Cocoapods for dependency management, while writing a Swift 2.0 app, and some of the dependencies require me to use 'use_frameworks!'.

I've defined my dependencies and run pod install, everything compiles and builds just fine so far. Here's the pod file.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'MyTarget' do
    pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'SwiftDate', '~> 1.2'
end

target 'MyTargetTests' do

end
```

The problem arrives when I created a new Scheme for my target. I only have one target, but I wanted to build a different configuration file with API urls based on if I build for 'Debug' or 'Release'.

So I created a new scheme, duplicated it from my default one, and only changed the Build configuration from Debug to Release.

Now, when I build I get this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-MyTarget
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I go to the Frameworks folder in my project, after trying to build with the Release config, I see that the libPods-MyTarget.a file is red, so missing.

If I then build for Debug again, everything works and the file libPods-MyTarget.a is not red anymore. So I opened the folders where my projects build into.

- Debug-iphoneios // this one have the libPods-MyTarget.a file
- Release-iphoneios // this one does not have the libPods-MyTarget.a file

Somewhere, somehow the Release config, for my release scheme doesn't get the pod frameworks moved into it, while the Debug configuration does. I can't figure out why.

The question is, how do I link the Pod frameworks into both Schemes and their respective 'Debug' and 'Release' folders?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up removing cocoapods completely following this (Removed the guide link, because it was not longer available)

Then I just did `pod install`, and everything works now, for both my schemes. I have no idea why, or how, and sorry for that. But now I can build my app again. I hope this is helpful for someone.

Comment: That guide is gone, but being able to nuke cocoapods should be a core command.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the guide alper, but I think what you have to do is just reinstall the pods, with the new existing scheme, so pods will build the dependencies for that target as well, then go to the Pod target in Xcode, and tell it which configuration to use.

Comment: I found that there is such a command: pod deintegrate. So every time I duplicate a configuration I do that. Also see this issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5246

Comment: Thanks for sharing! :)